# How to flag a module so that it doesn't get compiled?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Is it possible to not compile a module or file that's found under the lib directory when running `mix.compile`?

If so, how to do it or at least where in Mix's source can I look to find that out?

Comment: I  agree with José.  What use case is this?  Seems quite odd to have Elixir code in the directory and not have it be part of the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just give it the `.exs` extension? The question though is: why do you have something that is not meant to be compiled in `lib`? Maybe you want to put it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
unless some_reason_why_you_would_actually_compile_this_module do
  defmodule SomeProject.SomeModule do
    ...
  end
end
```

Another (almost certainly stupid) option would be to just delete the file for that module.

If you sometimes *would* like the module to be compiled, you'd still want to either do something like the example above or move the file to (or under) another top-level sub-directory of your project besides `lib/` (and modify your project's Mix configuration to include that sub-directory when appropriate or desired).